# Rmarkdown - Pandoc version issues while rendering R markdown in Linux environment

Tags: cabal, r-markdown, pandoc

I am trying to render a Rmarkdown file using the command below

```
Rscript -e "require( 'rmarkdown' ); render('/home/user/mydir/test.Rmd', 'html_document')"
```

which gave me an error

```
pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required
```

I installed Pandocs following the instructions here https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md#newer-systems-debianubuntufedora

First tried to get the standalone version and then tried the R studio route. I can see Pandoc in /home/user/mydir/ however when I do Pandoc -v , the version is 1.9

Hence I tried upgrading using cabal

```
yum install ghc
yum install cabal-install
cabal update
cabal install pandoc
```

However, this wont work and I get this error

```
base-4.5.0.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
```

Now after all this , I still have pandoc 9 and unable to render Rmarkdown . Any solutions ?

Comment: Try updating `/bin/pandoc` to symlink to the newly installed/RStudio-bundled binary.

Comment: Thanks .This is what I tried.  `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/pandoc /bin/pandoc` . However ,pandoc version is still 1.9.4.1

Comment: Maybe you need to update `/usr/bin/pandoc`. What does `which pandoc` returns? Also, what version of `pandoc` is bundled with your RStudio?

Comment: `which pandoc` returned `/usr/local/bin/pandoc` so I changed the symlink to that location `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/pandoc /usr/local/bin/pandoc` . However no luck . I am using the latest Rstudio so I am assuming it is the latest pandoc  version [link] https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/

Comment: have you tried `cabal install -f pandoc`? As a side note, going this way, you may want to install `pandoc-citeproc` too, it is a different cabal package

Comment: `Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal`. This is the error with `cabal install -f pandoc`